# Excel 100% Pie chart

Tags: excel, excel-2013, excel-charts

I have a scoring table for buying an appartement/house. See example below:

[image]

To summarize the columns:

- **Category:** Used to categorize into Price, Energy, Placement, Features (has Balcony, Garden, ...), ...
- **Sub Category:** Detailing into for example: Is it close to a school, grocery shops, common transportation, ...
- **W:** The quotation: How important is the Sub category? Let's say, the price is more important than the year the building was made.
- **/10:** The score on 10
  Result: Sub result.

At the start you see the **Total percentage (on 100%)**. So in this example I set **all scores to 5/10 which makes it 50% in total** (which would make this house worthless).

The idea is (in the graph on the right) to have the **pie chart show 50%** (half of the circle) and have the *detailing* (by category as shown in the G-column) **show on the right**.

Any ideas or opinions on how to do this?

Comment: Can you not just create another row for graphing, that balances the result to 100% (quite what you'd like to label it, I'm not sure)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you require. Something like this maybe?:

[image: SO27101001 example]

This involved:

1. summing all the ColumnG values other than G1 in G1, `=SUM(G2:G1048576)`
2. plotting columnG as Style 6 pie chart.
3. `=COUNT(G:G)-1` in H1 (returned `6`)
4. select the 'other' part of the pie (right-hand side) and for Series Options, Values in second plot entering the value for the previous step (ie `6`).
5. some formatting adjustments